# What is the difference between these 2 ways of creating a list of arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I dynamically create a list of arrays in JavaScript, that actually shows up in the Developer console as a list of arrays?

Just rephrased this question;  there are plenty of examples how to do this, and my code is working, but I'm getting 2 very different results from these 2 methods:

I tried this:

```
var volume = [];
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var item = new Array(2);
    item[0] = json[i].json_date;
    item[1] = json[i].volume;
    volume.push(item);
    }
```

So, this code works, and seems to create an array of arrays, but in the developer console the result of console.log(typeof volume[0]) is undefined.

If I create the array manually, it works much better:

```
var volume = [
    [1313964000000,23.17],
    [1314050400000,23.78],
    [1314741600000,25.24],
    [1314828000000,24.77],
    [1440021600000,82.69]
];
```

Now console.log(typeof volume[0]) is object.  And console.log(volume) results in: (5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)].  That's what I need, not just [].

I've spent the entire day searching for answers, and have tried many variations of this code, but can't seem to find code that will dynamically create that volume array to correctly show up as an array of arrays.

Has anyone else run into this?

Here is the full code:

```
var volume = [];

fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/TSLA").then(function(response) {
    if(response.ok) {
        response.json().then(function(json) {
            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++){
                volume.push(new Array(json[i].json_date, json[i].volume));
                }

            });
        } else {
            console.log('Network request failed with response ' + 
response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
        }
        });

        console.log(volume);
```

So, the answer from oknawe helped me to solve this problem; however in a way the question has still not been answered, because the volume array is only usable inside that fetch function.  Later in the code, the data is still there, but individual elements test as undefined...

Comment: Your code should work fine.  You're probably doing something else wrong (eg, not waiting for async).

Comment: What does the variable `json` look like? How are you getting that? (Try dumping that to the console.)

Comment: The json part is fine:  {signal_date: "2010-06-29T04:00:00.000Z", json_date: 1277769600000, open: 19, high: 25, low: 17.54, …} - just a bunch of records like that.

Comment: And yes, the code does work... but the type of arrays inside the main array is undefined for some reason, and no matter what I try, I can't get those inside arrays to show up as Array(2)

Comment: @RussKarlberg see my answer below. The loop will never get iterated over since `json.length` will be `undefined`

Comment: Let's revisit @SLaks comment because that's the only thing that makes sense. If you are doing some form of `json = asyncFunctionReturningAPromise()` or maybe `asyncFunction.then(response=>{json = response});` and later (outside the async callback)  `console.log(json)`; Then the console will show you the **live** object (json will be updated *in your console* when the data arrives), but you better believe that data is slow and  WILL be undefined when your loop runs. You need to put your array creation inside a callback or inside a .then() or use async/await.

Comment: yes, both issues are most likely causing the problem: 1. not iterating due to an undefined value and 2. code not executed inside the callback.

Comment: Wow, if that's the case, then I never would have figured this out.  I will post the rest of the code and see if I can figure out how to use something like async/await.  To be honest, I didn't know what to use between that, promises, callbacks, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length` of a JSON object will be `undefined` since objects do not have a `length` value. You can use `Object.keys` to get size but that won't do you much good since object values cannot be accessed by index:

```
var volume = [];
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
    // can't access using json[i] here
}
```

However, you can use `Object.keys(json)` or `Object.values(json)`
and do something like below:
*(you'll need to have code inside the json callback)*

```
let volume = [];
fetch('/api/foo/bar').then((data) => {
    return data.json();
}).then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
    Object.keys(json).forEach((obj) => {
        // obj = {"json_date": 1313964000000, "volume": 23.17, ...}
        console.log(obj);
        volume.push(new Array(obj["json_date"], obj["volume"]));
    });
    console.log(volume);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.error('There was a problem with the request');
})
```

Comment: @RussKarlberg - updated code above should help you fix the issue.

Comment: this code assumes the response is indeed an **object** not an **array** of objects

Comment: Ok, I made these updates to my code, the good news is that it's giving me the list of arrays that I need... but the elements of the array are all undefined...

Comment: Finally got it working - using volume.push(new Array(json[obj].json_date, json[obj].volume));

Comment: hard to know exact structure of your json response without seeing it, but glad to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine, assuming the variable `json` is structured as you expect. You can also try:

`let volume = json.map((i) => [i.json_date, i.volume]);`

(Provided your environment lets you use ES6.)

Instead of manually looping over the array, you can iterate over the contents of the array with the `map` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried that, and the code is certainly more succinct.  I am using the latest version of everything.  The json data is coming from an API, and that parts works fine.  But I need to create this array of arrays for loading into HighCharts, and that part is simply not working, with no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to oknawe, I got it working.  Using that code works, provided I use that volume array *inside* the fetch code.  Outside that, the volume array still contains data, but individual elements are undefined.  Many thanks to everyone who posted here!